# How to sort out by index(0) alphabelically or index(2) of the List<String> in the ArrayList<List<String>> as bellow

Tags: java, sorting

```
List<List<String>> sortItem = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
sortItem.add(Arrays.asList("ajack","2","3"));
sortItem.add(Arrays.asList("carry","5","6"));
sortItem.add(Arrays.asList("elvy","1","8"));
sortItem.add(Arrays.asList("zack","1","9"));
sortItem.add(Arrays.asList("dusk","1","15"));
sortItem.add(Arrays.asList("dawn","1","10"));
```

the result expected is the *sortItem* is sorted by index 0 alphabetically
or the *sortItem* is sorted  by index 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both requested sorts could be implemented using [Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<T>)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) where a different `Comparator` would be required for each sought sort.

Specifically, `Collections.sort(sortItem, Comparator.comparing(list -> list.get(0)));` would sort alphabetically on index 0, `Collections.sort(sortItem, Comparator.comparing(list -> list.get(2)));` would sort alphabetically on index 2 and `Collections.sort(sortItem, Comparator.comparingInt(list -> Integer.valueOf(list.get(2))));` would sort in numerically ascending order on index 2.

Comment: Nice for differentiating between alphabetical and numeric sorting on index 2 and making use of lambda expressions

Comment: You're welcome. :) Glad to help. Thanks for the acknowledgement.

Comment: Credit to @PaulBoddington from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46842172/1840078 below for the `Comparator.comparing()` and `.comparingInt()` ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using Java 8, you could implement 2 custom comparators to pass to the Collections.sort method.  Here is an example that will also return a comparison if for example, one or both lists aren't the correct size:

```
class sortInd0 implements Comparator<List<String>>{
    @Override
    public int compare(List<String> list1, List<String> list2){
        if(list1.size() >= 1 && list2.size() >= 1){
            return list1.get(0).compareTo(list2.get(0));
       }else if(list1.size() < list2.size()){
            return -1;
        }else if(list1.size() > list2.size()){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

class sortInd2 implements Comparator<List<String>>{
    @Override
    public int compare(List<String> list1, List<String> list2){
        if(list1.size() >= 3 && list2.size() >= 3){
            return Integer.valueOf(list1.get(2)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(list2.get(2)));
        }else if(list1.size() < list2.size()){
            return -1;
        }else if(list1.size() > list2.size()){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you're confident the lists will always be the right size, you could do away with the else if branches.

Then, to sort on index 0:

```
sortItem.sort(new sortInd0());
```

Or, to sort on index 2:

```
sortItem.sort(new sortInd2());
```

Comment: Plus one for considerating all cases and writing legal Comparators.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `List<String>` when writing your own class might be better.

```
public final class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final int id;

    public Person(String name, int age, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then, given a `List<Person>` you can easily sort on any property you like. For example

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
```

or

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));
```

Comment: I like the `Comparator.comparing()` and `Comparator.comparingInt()` ideas! I'll try to improve my answer with those.